# Property 'filter' does not exist on type object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, syntax-error, zustand

I'm working with zustand and typescript. I got this error on my code

```
Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'object'.ts(2339)
```

I don't know how to fix this problem.
I'm creating an object from my useStore library.
I tried usin 'type' but it throws these errors on the code editor
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/749ea.png)

**TS**

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import create from "zustand";

type PkState = {
    filter: "",
    pokemon: [],
  }


const useStore = create((PkState) => ({
 

  PkStateFilter: (filter) =>
    PkState((state) => ({
      ...state,
      filter,
    })),

  PkStatePokemon: (pokemon) =>
    PkState((state) => ({
      ...state,
      pokemon,
    })),
}));

//  input
const FilterInput = () => {
  const filter = useStore((state) => state.filter);
  const PkStateFilter = useStore((state) => state.PkStateFilter);
  return (  <input value={filter}  onChange=((evt)=>PkStateFilter(evt.target.value))  />
  )
  


};

function App() {
  return <div className="App"></div>;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You can only filter _arrays_, not objects.

Comment: @jonrsharpe  Okay, then how do I fix it ?. Can I convert that object on an array ?

Comment: If you're trying to get the filter property out of the store, you'll need to supply some type information about what the shape of the data in the store is - it'll be object by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define a type for your store.

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import create from "zustand";

type State = {
  filter: string;
  pokemon: Array<string>;
  setFilter: (filter: string) => void;
  setPokemon: (pokemon: Array<string>) => void;
};

// You have to use the type here
const useStore = create<State>((set) => ({
  filter: "", // set initial values here
  pokemon: [],

  setFilter: (filter) =>
    set((state) => ({
      ...state,
      filter
    })),

  setPokemon: (pokemon) =>
    set((state) => ({
      ...state,
      pokemon
    }))
}));

//  input
const FilterInput = () => {
  const filter = useStore((state) => state.filter);
  const setFilter = useStore((state) => state.setFilter);
  return (
    <input value={filter} onChange={(evt) => setFilter(evt.target.value)} />
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this will work, try with distracting `filter` on the next way:

```
 const { filter } = useStore((state) => state);
```

Also you can debug `useStore` with console.log, to check what returning:

```
 const returnedState = useStore((state) => state);

 // Check does `filter` exists in state
 console.warn('returnedState', returnedState);
```